# comparing two matrices columns in python (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Assuming I have two matrices, `A` of dimensions `r X c`, and `B` of dimensions `r X d` (i.e., both matrices have the same number of rows and a different number of columns). Now, I want to compare every column in `A` to every column in `B`. That is, I want to find all the pairs `(i,j)`, where column `i` in matrix `A` equals column `j` in matrix `B`. Obviously, this can be easily done with a loop but I was wondering if there is an efficient fancy numpy style way to do that (where the emphasis is on being efficient)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example ?

Comment: `np.where((A[:,None] == B[...,None]).all(0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function returns an array with column indices that are equal for both matrices.

```
def get_equal_columns(m1, m2):
    equal_column_indices = np.where((m1[:, None] == m2[..., None]).all(0))[0]
    return equal_column_indices
```